kas fails "build/../conf/layer.conf" not found
I'm currently figuring out from-scratch Yocto using kas.
While kas successfully checks out repos and parses its config, somehow it fails with the following error:
ERROR: Unable to parse /home/simon/source/raspi_rheaos/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/simon/source/raspi_rheaos/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py", line 145, in resolve_file(fn='/home/simon/source/raspi_rheaos/build/../conf/layer.conf', d=<bb.data_smart.DataSmart object at 0x7f8d974f27e0>):
         if not os.path.isfile(fn):
    >        raise IOError(errno.ENOENT, "file %s not found" % fn)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] file /home/simon/source/raspi_rheaos/build/../conf/layer.conf not found

2024-07-05 12:13:03 - ERROR    - Command "/home/simon/source/raspi_rheaos/layers/poky/bitbake/bin/bitbake -c build core-image-base" failed with error 1

There is no conf directory in the repository root, which is typical AFAIK.
Below is my dir structure:
├── README
├── build
│   ├── bitbake-cookerdaemon.log
│   ├── cache
│   ├── conf
│   ├── sstate-cache
│   ├── tmp
│   └── tmp-glibc
├── layers
│   ├── meta-openembedded
│   ├── meta-qt5
│   └── poky
├── meta-raspberrypi
│   ├── COPYING.MIT
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── classes
│   ├── conf
│   ├── docs
│   ├── dynamic-layers
│   ├── files
│   ├── img
│   ├── kas-poky-rpi.yml
│   ├── lib
│   ├── recipes-bsp
│   ├── recipes-connectivity
│   ├── recipes-core
│   ├── recipes-devtools
│   ├── recipes-graphics
│   ├── recipes-kernel
│   ├── recipes-multimedia
│   ├── recipes-sato
│   └── wic
├── meta-rheaos
│   └── conf
├── poky
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── LICENSE.GPL-2.0-only
│   ├── LICENSE.MIT
│   ├── MAINTAINERS.md
│   ├── MEMORIAM
│   ├── README.OE-Core.md
│   ├── README.hardware.md -> meta-yocto-bsp/README.hardware.md
│   ├── README.md -> README.poky.md
│   ├── README.poky.md -> meta-poky/README.poky.md
│   ├── README.qemu.md
│   ├── SECURITY.md
│   ├── bitbake
│   ├── contrib
│   ├── documentation
│   ├── meta
│   ├── meta-poky
│   ├── meta-selftest
│   ├── meta-skeleton
│   ├── meta-yocto-bsp
│   ├── oe-init-build-env
│   └── scripts
└── rheaos_kas.yaml

rheaos_kas.yaml is my kas configuration file which looks like this:
header:
  version: 14
  includes:
    - repo: meta-raspberrypi
      file: kas-poky-rpi.yml

# Set the machine to build for
machine: raspberrypi5

# Set the distro to build for
distro: rheaos
#distro: poky

# Set the repos
repos:
  meta-rheaos:
    path: meta-rheaos

  meta-raspberrypi:
    url: "https://github.com/agherzan/meta-raspberrypi.git"
    refspec: scarthgap

  poky:
    url: "https://git.yoctoproject.org/poky/"
    refspec: scarthgap
    layers:
      meta-poky:

I have not added any further recipes or layers, as I wanted a simple build to verify the image builds and is valid before continuing further. However, because bitbake is looking for a file it cannot find (i.e. is looking in the wrong location), the build cannot continue.
I have already verified that the Yocto build in general works, by following the instructions in the Yocto docs and build Poky without any further modifications.
What have I misconfigured to produce the error?

Did you figure this out? I'm curious...

Sadly no, I haven't figured it out yet. I've still got the kas configs, but have temporarily switched to manually using bitbake to get the distro working

I fixed this having the kas file within a layer (meta-/kas.yml). Either put it in one of the downloaded layers or create one

Sadly this didn't fix my issue. ERROR: Unable to parse /home/simon/source/raspi_rheaos/layers/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/parse/__init__.py.
I'm still getting this error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] file /home/simon/source/raspi_rheaos/build/../conf/layer.conf not found
